# Shiny sever fails when running demo app

Tags: r, shiny

I have installed R on my Centos 7 server, and can access it via my browser and launch a Shiny app. I also installed Shiny server on the machine.
The Shiny server comes up and I can connect to it and see the welcome screen.

[image: Shiny Server Welcome Screen]

However, when I enter a number of bins to test the demo app - the server fails (Firefox cannot contact the server on...).

[image: Shiny Server Failure]

These are the error message that appear in  /var/log/shiny-server.log :

```
[2018-05-07 12:00:12.415] [INFO] shiny-server - Starting listener on 0.0.0.0:3838
[2018-05-07 12:03:55.701] [ERROR] shiny-server - Uncaught exception: 
TypeError: Cannot read property 'readable' of null
[2018-05-07 12:03:55.702] [ERROR] shiny-server - TypeError: Cannot read 
property 'readable' of null
    at ServerResponse.ondrain (/opt/shiny-server/node_modules/http-proxy/lib/node-http-proxy/http-proxy.js:327:19)
    at ServerResponse.emit (events.js:92:17)
    at Socket.ondrain (http.js:1855:44)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:117:20)
    at onwriteDrain (_stream_writable.js:289:12)
    at afterWrite (_stream_writable.js:277:5)
    at onwrite (_stream_writable.js:270:7)
    at Socket.WritableState.onwrite (_stream_writable.js:97:5)
    at Object.afterWrite (net.js:731:12)
[2018-05-07 12:03:55.702] [INFO] shiny-server - Stopping listener on 
    0.0.0.0:3838
[2018-05-07 12:03:55.702] [INFO] shiny-server - Shutting down worker 
processes (with notification)

/opt/shiny-server/lib/main.js:367
  throw err;
        ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'readable' of null
    at ServerResponse.ondrain (/opt/shiny-server/node_modules/http-proxy/lib/node-http-proxy/http-proxy.js:327:19)
    at ServerResponse.emit (events.js:92:17)
    at Socket.ondrain (http.js:1855:44)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:117:20)
    at onwriteDrain (_stream_writable.js:289:12)
    at afterWrite (_stream_writable.js:277:5)
    at onwrite (_stream_writable.js:270:7)
    at Socket.WritableState.onwrite (_stream_writable.js:97:5)
    at Object.afterWrite (net.js:731:12)
```

What am I doing wrong? Thank you.

Comment: Do you get any (error) messages in the app specific log file?

Comment: @RalfStubner - just Execution halted.

Comment: What versions of R, Shiny Server and the shiny package do you have installed?

Comment: Shiny Server: shiny-server-1.4.2.786-rh5-x86_64.rpm, getRversion():
[1] ‘3.4.4’, packageVersion("shiny"): [1] ‘1.0.5’

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following these instructions -
[Shiny Installation](https://www.rstudio.com/products/shiny/download-server/)
I have updated the Shiny version to version 1.5.7.907

```
$ wget https://download3.rstudio.org/centos6.3/x86_64/shiny-server-1.5.7.907-rh6-x86_64.rpm
$ sudo yum install --nogpgcheck shiny-server-1.5.7.907-rh6-x86_64.rpm
```

This solved the issue.